# Java System.getProperty with sudo gets root

Tags: command-line, java, sudo

This question is better asked here than in stack overflow since it is more related to Ubuntu than the actual programming language. Here are two different ways to get the path to a file. The first one is to have a default path and hardcode it. The second option is to use the `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))` offered in Java programming language. For more context, I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Java 17 with maven. Unfortunately, I can not change the Ubuntu.

I deployed the jar file in the Ubuntu. The issue is that I must run the jar file with `sudo` to get the sudo privileges. But in this case, the `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))` will return `root/home` instead of `user/home`.

Do you have any idea how I should do it in this case?

Comment: If you run it as root, root's home directory is commonly `/root`. Why does it have to be executed as root, and why does it in that case need the users home directory?

Comment: @vidarlo My application is just the intent based and more processes and must be run as root to start and stop other processes that run as root, plus many other thins and it is better to just run the main app as root than put for each time sudo and the password.

Comment: Why do you need the home directory of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate why the `.jar` needs `sudo` (`root`), and could "capabilities" replace `sudo`.

Now, the hack:

Read `man sudo sudoers sudoedit`. Define an environment variable to hold the home directory, tell `sudoers` to export it to the invoked environment. Use a new environment variable for this, Do Not use `$HOME`. Do:

```
export userhome="$HOME"
sudo ... .jar
```

and refer to the `userhome` environment variable in the `.jar`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @iliealexandru Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.

Comment: Now after I have checked your solution, but when I try to refer it in the .jar  file it give me "null". Sorry, but it took some time to get back home.